# Integer solutions for $x^3=y^2+5$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, mordell-curves

I have been able to solve the equation $x^3=y^2+a$ for integers where $1 \leq a \leq 4$ by splitting in $\Bbb Z [i\sqrt a]$. However as a natural continuation I would like to know whether the equation $x^3=y^2+5$ can be solved using elementary methods. Seems this case is much tougher though .I would like some hints on how to proceed.

Comment: It might be helpful, if you show how you solved the cases $a=1,2,3,4$.

Comment: Did you try $x^3-1=y^2+4=(y+2i)(y-2i)$ ?

Comment: I basically showed that $(y+i), (y-i) $ are necessarily coprime in $Z[i]$. And then solved for the equation $y+i=(a+ib)^3$ For the equation $x^3=y^2+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working mod 4 we see that $y$ must be even and $x=1\bmod4$. Now we have $$y^2+4=x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$$ But $x^2+x+1=3\bmod4$, so $x^2+x+1$ is odd. It is also positive, so it must be at least 3. Hence it must have a prime factor $p=3\bmod4$. So $y^2+4=0\bmod p$, in other words -4 is a quadratic residue of $p$. But that implies that $p=1\bmod 4$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Write $$ (x-1)(x^2+x+1) = y^2+4$$

If $x\equiv_4 0$ then $x-1\equiv_4 3$ so there is a prime $p\equiv_4 3$ such that $p\mid x-1$. So $p\mid y^2+2^2$ so $p\mid 2$, a contradiction!

If $x\equiv_4 1$ then $x^2+x+1\equiv_4 3$ so there is a prime $p\equiv_4 3$ such that $p\mid x^2+x+1$. So $p\mid y^2+2^2$ so $p\mid 2$, a contradiction!

If $x\equiv_4 2$ then $x^2+x+1\equiv_4 3$ so there is a prime $p\equiv_4 3$ such that $p\mid x^2+x+1$. So $p\mid y^2+2^2$ so $p\mid 2$, a contradiction!

We are left with the case $x\equiv_4 3$ ....

Comment: $x$ even is dismissed seeing the equation $mod 4$ rightaway. Because RHS is $1,2 mod 4$.

Comment: $p|y^2+2^2$ implies $p|2$? Why?

Comment: $y^2$ is either 0 or 1 mod 4....so $y^2+1$ is 1 or 2 mod 4. Now if $x$ is even that is  0,2 mod 4, cubing it will yeild a number that is $0 mod 4$.

Comment: @almagest You are asking me why and you wrote that too. Did you steal ''your solution''?